# Detecting "ended" event in Blackberry website after playing video

Tags: javascript, events, blackberry, video, detect

We develop a video website for blackberry. When the user click in a video thumb we redirect him to the video file and the native video player is launched. When the video completes or the user press the Back button it come backs to the site. Its there any way to detect when the video has finished? or maybe when the user goes back to the page?

FYI: we cannot use html5!

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?

Comment: No, we never find out how to capture the end of a video playback in Blackberry without html5. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Listen for `blur` and `focus` events on the window itself.